# Multivariate testing

Tags: bayesian, ab-test

I'm going to run a test with 4 different variants (3 variants and a control group), and we want to find the variant with the highest conversion.

Are there any resources/methods in R/python to:

- Perform a test to tell if a variant converts significantly better than the others?
- Calculate sample size before performing this test?

Either frequentist or Bayesian methods work for me, thanks! The context is that the amount of data is not huge, I have around 5000 users every month in that funnel.

Comment: worth to have a look: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesAB/vignettes/introduction.html for the 2nd point this framework won't tell you the sample size a priori but would provide a measure of confidence of how better is an option over another one, so you can decide when to stop the experiment based on that

Comment: Check out https://github.com/spotify/confidence for a python alternative that can do both.